# Почему в словах "милостивый и юродивый" пишется суффикс ИВ?

Tags: орфография, суффиксы

Понятное дело, это **слова-исключения**, и ни у кого не вызывает сомнения, что исключения надо запоминать. Но кто и когда сделал их исключениями? **А главное — почему?**

Я считаю, что **все исключения надо объяснять.** Если дети не спрашивают, откуда они берутся, то здесь есть о чем подумать взрослым: почему они всё принимают на веру? почему не любопытны? почему привыкли получать только готовые знания?

Но вот ученик спросил об **исключениях, подтверждающих правило**, и привел в качестве примера два этих слова. Правда, фраза эта оказалась неверной, но тем не менее именно об этих исключениях он вспомнил.

https://vagarius.livejournal.com/18369.html

https://pantv.livejournal.com/1935708.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти все исключения связаны с традицией написания, написание данных слов тоже соответствует традиции.

Есть суффиксы, характерные с давнего времени только для русского (великорусского) языка или только для восточнославянской языковой группы. Сюда относятся -ник и -щик для обозначения действующих лиц мужского пола,  -ък-а  для обозначения определённого действия: возъка (от возить), уборка и т. п., и суффикс прилагательных -чив-ъ (в современном русском: уступчивый, опрометчивый и т. п.).

Один из самых продуктивных суффиксов прилагательных  был -ив: грязивый: „по грязивымъ мЪстомъ"— в „Слове о полку Игореве"; струпивый, памятивый (ныне: памятливый) и пр., в современном русском спесивый и т. д.], потом -лив- (л--ив), как следствие переразложения основы: бодль (шип): бодл-ив-ый бод-лив-ый (при наличии .„бодати"), далее: гневливый, завистливый и т. д. Наконец, позже других суффиксов, к XVI в., на русской почве возникает суффикс -чив-(ч -J- ив), также в результате переразложения основы: лайца (ругатель, от „лаяти"), лайч-ив-ый лай-чив-ьш (из употребления вышли), далее: заносчивый, доверчивый и т. д.

Новые суффиксы -лив- и особенно -чив- в современном русском языке явно вытесняют старый суффикс -ив- в словах этой группы, он остаётся только под ударением. Для слова милостивый многие словари дают и просторечный вариант милостливый (по аналогии с счастье-счастливый и подобными) Старославянизм юродивый имеет русский вариант уродливый, но сейчас  значения слов разошлись.  http://www.booksshare.net/index.php?author=chernih-pya&book=1952&category=lunguistics&id1=4&page=121

Вообще, слово юродивый - тема целого исследования. Слово «юродивый» возникло в общеславянский период. В «Этимологическом словаре» Фасмера сказано: «Юродивый, др.-русск. ЮРОДИВЪ, начиная с XIV в. До этого – УРОДИВЪ.

Г. П. Цыганенко, предположив общеславянский характер слова «урод», объясняет его образование от существительного «родъ» <семья, род>, <порода> с приставкой у– в отрицательном значении, и получается «<как бы врожденный не в род>, <чем-то отличающийся от остальных в роду> (как положительным, так и отрицательным), отсюда в одних языках положительная окраска семантики (ср. польск. uroda <красота, миловидность>; укр. врода <красота, краса>, где в– – вариант у-, вродливий, уродливий <красивый, пригожий>), а в других – нейтральная или отрицат., как в рус. диал. урода <стать, стан, природа>, литерат. урод <чел. с физическими недостатками>» [10, с. 451]. Кстати, в древнерусской традиции слово «урод» имело положительное значение. Так назывался сын-первенец, который по традиции становился главным наследником рода. Ему всегда доставался отчий дом после смерти родителей. На первенца ложилась забота о престарелых отце и матери, тогда как второй и все последующие сыновья обычно уходили из отчего дома и строили свои семьи вне его стен. Потому-то старшего сына и звали «уродом», что буквально означало того, кто остается у рода.

Русское «уродливый» происходит от глагола «уродовати», что первоначально имело значение «безумствовать». Это значение затем стало передавать церковнославянское «юродствовати» и его производные (юродивый, юродство и другие). А «уродовати» и его производные «урод», «уродина», «уродливый» в русском языке стали указывать не на умственные, а на физические недостатки.

Обозначенные выше значения  слова «юродивый» разделились к XVII в., когда обозначение «юродивый» закрепилось именно за святым, из благочестивых побуждений скрывавшимся под личиной безумца, а первоначальное «урод» – за калекой.

Делаем вывод: пара юродивый-уродливый поначалу различалась только происхождением (церковнославянизм и русизм), а затем стала различаться и значениями.

Comment: Людмила. спасибо за ответ, пока думаю над темой.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь суффикс отражает *склонность* к проявлению определенного свойства (милости) или к соответствующему действию (юродствованию). Аналогично: незлобивый, находчивый, бодливый, дождливый, противоречивый и многое др.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, за ответ, я думаю примерно в одинаковом с Вами направлении. Но вот только такой вопрос: ведь суффиксы ИВ/ЛИВ/ЧИВ все проявляют такую склонность к действию или признаку Можно сравнить: жалостливый, совестливый. Чем они отличаются от прилагательного "милостивый"? Почему бы не написать милостливый, вот и не было бы исключения.  А пара уродливый - юродивый как образовалась?

Answer (score 1):

Итак, **изначально в языке был только суффикс ИВ**. Согласно словарю Черных, в др.-рус. языке с XI века существовало слово ***уродивый*** (ст.-сл. вариант ***юродивый***), однако впоследствии оно было переоформлено в ***уродливый*** (в связи с изменением значения и появлением суффикса ЛИВ).

В современном языке **сосуществуют суффиксы ИВ и ЛИВ,** имеющие сходное значение, при этом **суффикс ИВ** назван регулярным, но непродуктивным. Это означает, что он встречается достаточно часто, но для образования новых слов уже не используется.

А вот **суффикс ЛИВ** является продуктивным и регулярным. Его фонетическая форма удобна для присоединения к различным основам, также он может быть ударным и безударным.

**Слова с ударным суффиксом ИВ**: красивый, ленивый, льстивый, плаксивый, плешивый, правдивый, фальшивый, червивый. Мы видим, что суффикс присоединяется преимущественно к односложной основе, суффикс ЛИВ к этим словам фонетически не подходит.

Если исходное существительное имеет **суффикс ОСТЬ**, то для образования прилагательных  обычно используется суффикс ЛИВ: *жалостливый, совестливый*.

Вероятно, слово ***милостивый*** (суффикс ИВ) было начальной формой, но впоследствии (с появлением суффикса ЛИВ) **не было переоформлено в** ***милостливый*** по образцу *жалость — жалостливый, совесть — совестливый*.

Это, возможно,  связано с тем, что существительное ***милость*** по значению соотносится с глаголом ***миловать***, а не с прилагательным ***милый***, хотя исторически они связаны друг с другом.